# Postgres/SQL: modeling charges and refunds against a payment source

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have the following models and I want to write a query which will return unspent credits. Credits have many charges which in turn have many refunds. My attempt at the query so far is below but I have found a problem with it and need a little help. All the `amount` columns are positive.

```
Credit
id (integer)
amount (decimal)

Charge
id (integer)
credit_id (integer)
amount (decimal)

Refund
id (integer)
charge_id (integer)
amount (decimal)
```

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT credits.*,
"credits"."amount" - coalesce(sum("charges"."amount"), 0) + coalesce(sum("refunds"."amount"), 0) AS unspent_amount 
FROM "credits"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "charges" ON "charges"."credit_id" = "credits"."id"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "refunds" ON "refunds"."charge_id" = "charges"."id"
GROUP BY "credits"."id"
HAVING "credits"."amount" > coalesce(sum("charges"."amount"), 0) - coalesce(sum("refunds"."amount"), 0) LIMIT 1
```

The problem I have encountered is that if a charge has many refunds, the sum of the charges amount will be N* where N is the number of refunds. I want to count the charge amount only once for each charge id.

Ultimately I want credits where credits.amount > sum of charges_against_credits.amount - refunds_for_those_charges.amount. How can I achieve this?

EDIT:

Here are some sample records which will reproduce the problem:

```
credits
id 1
amount 25.0

charges
id 1
credit_id 1
amount 25.0

refunds
id 1
charge_id 1
amount 20.0
-----------
id 2
charge_id 1
amount 5.0
```

EDIT 2:

Expected output:

```
credits:
1 row:
id: 1, amount: 25.0, unspent_amount: 25.0
```

Comment: can you give sample records?

Comment: Sure! Will add that right now.

Comment: I've added the expected output :-)

Comment: can there be possibly many charges for a single credit just like many refunds on a single charge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.ID,
        (a.amount - COALESCE(b.totalCharges, 0)) + COALESCE(c.totalRefunds, 0) AS unspent_amount
FROM    credits AS a
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  credit_ID, SUM(amount) totalCharges
            FROM    charges
            GROUP   BY credit_ID
        ) AS b  ON a.ID = b.credit_ID
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  aa.credit_ID, SUM(bb.amount) totalRefunds
            FROM    charges AS aa
                    LEFT JOIN Refund AS bb
                        ON  aa.ID = bb.Charge_ID
            GROUP   BY aa.credit_ID
        ) AS c  ON b.credit_ID = c.credit_ID
--  WHERE   clause ...here....
```

Comment: Thanks for this - I learned a few things about SQL from your answer.

Comment: you're welcome. actually, the second subquery need to join `charges` with `refund` since you are `refund` via an auto incremented field of `charges..

Comment: I ended up doing the left join onto refunds inside the left join onto charges. The missing link for me was the ability to left join onto the result of a subquery.